# Putting a point over pixels with highest DN values within grids in QGIS

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, raster-to-point

I have a raster layer in greyscale, and a vector layer that is 3 x 3 m grid. One of the attributes within the grid cell layer is the value of the highest DN number within that grid cell. I just need to get a point over the highest pixel for each grid cell. That's it.

I've tried a number of methods involving converting pixels to points so you can table join, but there's too many grid cells and QGIS crashes!

Comment: @MrXsquared - no it doesn't. It's also unanswered!

Comment: The comment means that this question is considered to be a duplicate of the other one, so this question risks to be closed. Please see [tour]